# Solr not indexing all the vertices DSE

Tags: graph, solr, cassandra, datastax

We are using DSE with Graph version 6.0 and we are enabling Solr on a vertex label to support spatial search and queries.

we have a multipolygon dataset and we have indexed it using solr JTS library. However, solr is not indexing whole datasets it just limiting to few .. we have 560 nodes with vertex label as regions and this node has a property named boundary which is of type text and we store multipolygon/polygon data. Now to enable geospatial search on this we indexed this using solr as mentioned in DSE documentation but Solr is not indexing all the nodes . It is just indexing 128 out of 560 nodes. Any idea what is limiting solr to index full data sets

Comment: Did you force DSE to rebuild existing indexes, or you're adding fresh data?

Comment: Yes Alex, I did force to rebuild it.

Comment: Can you join https://academy.datastax.com/slack - maybe people in #graph room could help? I'm unfortunately not graph expert (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue is solved. It was data issue. Improper data was loaded from csv to graph database and while running Solr indexes on this data it was validating the data